# How to pass user name to react page?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this react code.

Apps.js

```
// react-router-auth
import React, {useState} from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Link, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import PrivateRoute from './PrivateRoute';
import Home from './pages/Home';
import Admin from './pages/Admin';
import Login from "./pages/Login";
import Signup from "./pages/Signup";

import { AuthContext } from "./context/auth";

function App(props) {
    const [authTokens, setAuthTokens] = useState();
    const setTokens = (data) => {
        localStorage.setItem("tokens", JSON.stringify(data));
        setAuthTokens(data);
    }

    return (
        <AuthContext.Provider value={{ authTokens, setAuthTokens: setTokens }}>
            <Router>
                <div>
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <Link to="/">Home Page</Link>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <Link to={{ pathname: "/admin", state:{username: props.location}}}>Admin Page</Link>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <Link to={{ pathname: "/login", state:{referer: props.location}}}>Login Page</Link>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <Link to={{ pathname: "/signup", state:{referer: props.location}}}>Sign Up Page</Link>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <p>
                        stuff
                    </p>

                    <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
                    <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
                    <Route path="/signup" component={Signup} />
                    <PrivateRoute path="/admin" component={Admin} />

                </div>
            </Router>
        </AuthContext.Provider>);
}

export default App;
```

Login.js

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Link, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
import axios from 'axios';
import logoImg from "../img/logo.svg";
import { Card, Logo, Form, Input, Button, Error } from '../components/AuthForms';
import { useAuth } from "../context/auth";

function Login(props) {
    const [isLoggedIn, setLoggedIn] = useState(false);
    const [isError, setIsError] = useState(false);
    const [userName, setUserName] = useState("");
    const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
    const { setAuthTokens } = useAuth();
    const referer = props.location.state.referer || '/';

    function postLogin() {
       console.log('postLogin called.');
       const something = axios.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/rest-auth/login/', {"username" : userName, "password": password} ).then(
           result => {
               console.log('postLogin called. username is ' + userName);
               if( result.status === 200 ) {
                   setAuthTokens(result.data);
                   setLoggedIn(true);
                   setUserName(userName=> userName);
               } else {
                   setIsError(true);
               }
           }).catch(e=>{setIsError(true);}
       );
       console.log('postLogin end. something is :');
       console.log(something);
    } // end postLogin

    if (isLoggedIn) {
        console.log('postLogin isLoggedIn is true and referer is ' + referer);
        return <Redirect to={referer} />;
    }

    return (
        <Card>
            <Logo src={logoImg} />
            <Form>
                <Input
                    type="username"
                    value={userName}
                    onChange={e=>{
                        setUserName(e.target.value);
                    }}
                    placeholder="username"
                />
                <Input
                    type="password"
                    value={password}
                    onChange={e=>{
                        setPassword(e.target.value);
                    }}
                    placeholder="password"
                />
                <Button onClick={postLogin}>Sign In</Button>
            </Form>
            <Link to="/signup">Don't have an account?</Link>
            { isError&& <Error>The username or password provider were incorrect.</Error>}
        </Card>
    );
}

export default Login;
```

Admin.js

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Button } from "../components/AuthForms"
import {useAuth} from "../context/auth";

function Admin(props) {
    const  { setAuthTokens } = useAuth();
    const [userName, setUserName] = useState();
    function  logOut () {
        setAuthTokens();
    }
    return (
    <div>
        <div>Admin Page userName is [{props.username}]</div>
        <div>Admin Page userName is [{userName}]</div>
        <Button onClick={logOut}>Log out</Button>
    </div>);
}

export default Admin;
```

When I login I do not see the userName. 
What a I doing wrong?

[image]

Update: I also have this file, auth.js

```
import { createContext, useContext } from 'react';

export const AuthContext = createContext();

export function useAuth() {
    return useContext(AuthContext);
}
```

Comment: What are you try to do with this line `<Link to={{ pathname: "/admin", state:{username: props.location}}}>Admin Page</Link>`, you are assigning `props.location` in username

Comment: From your admin functional component you suppose to get the username using `props.location.state.username`

Comment: try `console.log(props)` in  `function Admin(props) {console.log(props)}` and see which property of props hold the userName.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're not passing the property username to the Admin page. The property is being set in Login page and its not assigned to the context or the Admin page.

One of the easiest ways of setting a logged in Username is setting it in localstorage and retrieving it in the pages you need. This is obviously very exploitable and not recommended for sensitive data.

The other workaround is using React's Context APIs. In your AuthContext you can use `useState(username, setUsername) = (window.localStorage.getItem('username') || '')` and pass it down as props. You can retrieve the setUsername function in the login page and update it in the admin page.

```
export const AuthContext = createContext();

const AuthContextProvider = (props) => {
    const [username, setUsername] = useState(null);

    return (
        <AuthContext.Provider
            value={{
                data: username,
                updateUserName: (value) => {
                    setUsername(value)
                }
            }}>
            {props.children}
        </AuthContext.Provider>
    );
};
```

Comment: Thanks Aabhushan I have set up a AuthContext.  I have posted the code I have for this AuthContext.  Could you please take a look and see what I am doing wrong there?